# How can I switch between Mongo and Postgres using TypeORM with NestJS?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I have written my backend to use MongoDB but I would like to make the existing solution DB agnostic.

Is there an easier way to switch between Postgres and Mongo DB?

When trying to migrate to Postgres I had to manually comment out the ObjectID field (a mandatory primary key for MongoDB).

I would like to know if there is an easier way to define entities in TypeORM without having to manually comment out columns when migrating to different DB

Comment: MongoDB is a document-oriented database while PostgreSQL is a relational database, the way of building them is completely different. I find it difficult to migrate, but doing a quick research on Google, i found this https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/export-mongodb-to-sql-database/ I hope it helps.